# Unity2d Jumping like teleport

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on Unity2d `Sprite` but something is wrong: in my code when I press the jump button my character jump like teleport, it go very fast in the Up direction. The gravity is 9 and my `Rigidbody2D` mass is 1. My code is this:

```cs
if(isGrounded == true && moveH == 0) {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J)) {

        anim.SetBool("str_jump", true);
        //rgBody.velocity = new Vector2(0,jumpHeight);                
        //rgBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);                
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x,
                                         transform.position.y * jumpHeight);
        isGrounded = false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If your jump is too high, you have to use a variable to modify the height of the jump. In your case, you are using the `jumpHeight` as the variable to modify the height of your jump.

Decreasing `jumpHeight` should **solve** your problem. Note that if `jumpHeight` is declared as public (`public float jumpHeight;`), you have to change the variable from the Editor or a function because it will not use the number assigned to it when it was declared. It will use whatever that is assigned to it from the Editor.

For example, when you have `public float jumpHeight = 4;` but the value is set to `0` in the editor, `0` will be used as the value not `4`.

Also you have to use `rgBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);`. Uncomment it and then remove the `transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y *jumpHeight);` line of code.

If this does not solve your problem, then you have to update your question with your complete code.

Answer (score 1):

For a nice jump you could also use `rgBody.AddForce((Vector2.up * jumpHeight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);` It simulates an impact on your object and you get a nice jump simulation.

Do not forget to declare the `public float jumpHeigt = 4f;` like "Programmer" said it before.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use transform.position '+=' instead of just '='. This way you're adding to it's position and not setting it to a certain number(that's why it's teleporting like that). Tho this method only suits horizontal movement in my opinion(if it's  a sideview game). For jumping, using AddForce would be way better.

Answer (score -1):

Simply reducing the jumpHeight value will fix the initial issue of the jump being too high.

However if you want a more realistic 'jump' you may want to utilise `Rigidbody2D.velocity` simply having `rgBody.velocity = new Vector2(rgBody.velocity.x, jumpHeight);` should create a nice smooth jump.

If you use the `Rigidbody2D.velocity` instead of simply changing the transform means that you can alter values such as Gravity Scale and this will make a noticeable difference on the movement of your player. You can play around with different jumpHeight and Gravity Scale values to find what works best for your game.